# フェイルオーバー時のpostgresql.pid処理方法について

Tags: postgresql

RHEL7環境下のpostgresqlサーバをpacemakerにて冗長化を行っております。しかし、フェイルオーバー時にpostgresql.pidが残ってしまい、postgresqlサービスの自動起動ができません。手動で消すことで動作はしますが、根本的な解決にはなりません。どのような対処方法がありますでしょうか。

Comment: pidファイルを消せば起動するのであれば対処方法としては自動で消すということになりますがその方法がわからないという質問でしょうか。それとも、そうではない何か別の対処方法が知りたいということでしょうか。

Comment: 「フェイル」した方の pid ファイルが残るということであれば、問題を解決する前に起動してしまわないよう安全措置とも言えるのでは？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[postggresql.orgのyumリポジトリ](https://yum.postgresql.org/)からダウンロードできるpostgresqlであれば、PIDファイルが残っていても`pg_ctl`コマンド(`pg_ctl -w start`)で起動してくれると思います。(警告は出ますが)

＃9.6.5で試してみました。

1. pacemakerでのpostgresqlの起動方法が「`pg_ctl`」になっているか確認してはどうでしょうか?
2. RedHat提供のpostgresqlを利用しているのであれば、postgresql.orgが提供しているそれに置き換えてみるのはどうでしょうか?

Comment: systemd以外から起動するのがポイントなのですね。無事に起動できました。ありがとうございます。